# Zendframework2 using Doctrine orderBy is not "ordering" at all

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, sql-order-by

I really am at a point where I am out of Ideas. I just want to order categories with Doctrine. After a litle doctrine documentation reading I uses following in my Controller:

```
$categories = $em->getRepository('\Cbox\Entity\Category')->findBy(array('title' =>'news'), array('createdTime' => 'DESC'));
```

Both Column's exist nor do I get a PHP/Doctrine/Mysql Error. Is this the right aproach? I also tried using orderBy Annotations in my Entity with no success either:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cbox\Entity\Category", mappedBy="box")
* @ORM\OrderBy({"createdTime" = "DESC"})
*/
protected $category;
```

I also did read about the QueryBuilder and the DQL but this just seems to be a litle bit of an overkill to get the orderBy set.

Any help would be much appreciated. I also do hope thats enough code for you guys to get the picture. But I rather have the "problematic" parts shown here then tons of code.

Comment: the second parameter of the findBy functions is for ordering, so that is correct. I am wondering, what do you get back? Nothing or a not correctly ordered list? And of what type/format is "createdTime"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
 $qb->select('u')
 ->from('Cbox\Entity\Category u')
 ->where('u.title = :title')
 ->orderBy('u.createdTime', 'DESC')
 ->setParameter('title', news);
```

Now if **Cbox\Entity\Category** or **\Cbox\Entity\Category** is correct entity this must work. 
Here is another approach you can do same thing without **setParameter()** but i will not recommend it.

```
  $qb->select('u')
 ->from('Cbox\Entity\Category u')
 ->where('u.title = news')
 ->orderBy('u.createdTime', 'DESC');
```

Further more if you want see how to fetch result out of **$qb** i suggest you follow this link http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html